# When the maximum efficiency of a linear amplifier occurs?

Tags: analog, linear-regulator

[image]

When measuring the efficiency of a linear amplifier (say a class AB above), we say that maximum efficiency occurs when the linear amplifier delivers maximum current to the load (output voltage is also at maximum). However, I do not understand the “maximum current delivered to the load” refers to which of the following cases:

Case 1

- As output voltage of a linear amplifier varies in a sinusoidal way, maximum efficiency happens at the peak (or the trough) of the wave.
- By the same token minimum efficiency happens when the output voltage is at the DC value.

[image]

Case 2

- Maximum efficiency happens when the amplitude of the output voltage is closest to the supply voltage.
- Efficiency drops when the amplitude of the output voltage decreases.

[image]

I should be grateful if anyone can

- Indicate whether max efficiency refers to Case 1 or Case 2.
- Correct any of the misunderstanding in the above description.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Case 2 is the normal understanding, efficiency figures are usually computed over the complete cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but with different definitions of "efficiency".

Usually when folks talk about the efficiency of an amplifier, they're specifically talking about the *average* efficiency, *with sine wave input* and *without appreciable distortion*.

In your case 1, you are talking about the instantaneous efficiency of the amplifier.  So yes, the amplifier is most efficient at that moment when the voltage drop across the amplifying elements is zero.

In your case 2, you are talking about the usual definition.  So, the amplifier is most efficient when the output is just kissing the supply rails (note that for some amplifiers you can't get to the supply rails without appreciable distortion -- usually such an amplifier is specified as having a certain power output *at that point*, and a certain distortion and (maybe) efficiency).

Note that an amplifier is *most* efficient if it takes a sine wave in and delivers a square wave to the load, with said square wave hitting the supply rails.  Efficiency (at least in terms of total power out vs. total supply power) can approach 100%!  Yay!
Unfortunately, the distortion is what is known in some circles as "a little bit high".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in a real application, when engineers talk about efficiency, they refer to case 2, i.e. RMS power delivered to the load divided by the DC power (as mentioned by Barry above). Is it correct?

Comment: However, I don't quite understand your last point. You mentioned that an amplifier is most efficient if it take a sine input and delivers a square wave to the load. If it is the case, the linear amplifier becomes nonlinear. The transistors may have saturated and the output waveform is distorted. Please correct me if I have any misunderstanding. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry -- it was low humor.  Yes, the amplifier is most efficient.  But the customer way be just a bit angry with you when you deliver it.

Comment: So, in a formal way, can we say engineers trade efficiency with linearity when designing linear amplifiers? Thanks.

Comment: Well, yes, but actually running into the rail is cheating.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about instantaneous efficiency rather than the efficiency over one cycle of the input waveform which is what is usually considered. The latter efficiency is the ratio of the RMS power delivered to the load divided by the DC input power. For a sine wave and a linear class A amplifier the maximum efficiency is 50% which occurs when the output voltage reaches the supply voltage and is only possible in an ideal amplifier for which the output transistors have no internal voltage drop at maximum output.As the output voltage drops, the efficiency will drop also because the difference between the output voltage and the DC power supply now appears across the transistor and, when multiplied by the output current, this represents a power loss.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.